# Is FrameLayout Responsible for Drawing Children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm wondering if a `FrameLayout` is responsible for drawing its children. According to the Android docs I would think that it is:

> In turn, each ViewGroup is responsible for requesting each of its
>   children to be drawn (with the draw() method) and each View is
>   responsible for drawing itself.

However, when I extend `FrameLayout` and override its `onDraw()` method to do nothing, its children are still drawn.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Do nothing by commenting out super call.
    // However, children are still drawn
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

My guess is that there is another method responsible for drawing all of the layout's children. However, I'm not sure what that method is.

Comment: **(with the draw() method)**

Comment: Ah, thanks! For some reason I thought that it called it's children's `draw()` method inside its `onDraw()` method. Makes more sense that it would do it inside its own `draw()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of *onDraw()*,  override *draw()* method